# How to plot and change the plotfunction at the same time?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot points, and while doing so have a slidebar that I can adjust, which changes the function. 
I found this example [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/examles/widgets/slider_demo.html) that works. Now I want to plot points in a loop and change the function while the loop is still running.

I changed the example and it has become this. Problem: the points are being plotted **inside the reset button!**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button
import random
import time

x=[]
y=[]
a=5

fig = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
schuifa = Slider(plt.axes([0.125, 0.1, 0.775, 0.03],axisbg='lightgoldenrodyellow'), 'a', 0, 30.0, valinit=1)

def update(val):
    a=schuifa.val
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

schuifa.on_changed(update)

button = Button(plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04]),'Reset',color='lightgoldenrodyellow', hovercolor='0.975')

def reset(event):
    schuifa.reset()

button.on_clicked(reset)

for t in range(0,5):
    s=a*random.random()
    x.append(t)
    y.append(s)

#plt.axis([0, 1, -10, 10])
plt.scatter(t,s)

#fig.canvas.draw_idle()
plt.draw()

plt.show()
time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Your example link is invalid